Glue Job Stuck at write_dynamic_frame.from_options()
When running the below script, I get all the way to the write portion without issue. S3 bucket gets populated with data, the transformation happens correctly, etc. But my job just runs and runs without writing the data to Redshift. No errors. Nothing in the logs that I can find that specifies any connection or write issues.
There are no locks on the destination table. It does exist. The connection params work to get the data, just not put. What gives?
various imports...

def get_secret(secret_name, region_name):
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(service_name='secretsmanager', region_name=region_name)
    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
    secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
    return eval(secret)  

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', "TempDir"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

region_name = "" 
secret_name = ""  
redshift_temp_dir = args["TempDir"]
credentials = get_secret(secret_name, region_name)
redshift_user = credentials['username']
redshift_password = credentials['password']

redshift_connection_options = {
    "url": "",
    "dbtable": "",
    "user": redshift_user,
    "password": redshift_password,
    "redshiftTmpDir": redshift_temp_dir
}

source_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="redshift",
    connection_options=redshift_connection_options,
    transformation_ctx="source_df"
)

renamed_df = source_df.toDF().withColumn("lastupdatedtimestamp", col("lastupdatedtimestamp").cast("int"))
renamed_dynamic_df = DynamicFrame.fromDF(renamed_df, glueContext, "renamed_dynamic_df")

redshift_connection_options2 = {
    "url": "",
    "dbtable": "",
    "user": redshift_user,
    "password": redshift_password,
    "redshiftTmpDir": redshift_temp_dir
}

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=renamed_dynamic_df,
    connection_type="redshift",
    connection_options=redshift_connection_options2,
    transformation_ctx="target_df"
)

job.commit()


Any help is appreciated

DId you check the Role used by the Glue job has Redshift Write permissions? The Glue connection will need access to the same VPC that Redshift uses. Try using from_jdbc_conf() instead of from_options(). Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-redshift-home.html

@AnanthTirumanur, that's interesting. So even though I was able to access Redshift via Read with credentials from secrets manager, I still need a role to Write? Can I attach a policy to the execution role? Or do I need a separate role that is passed in as a parameter, like in the documentation you linked (thank you for that by the way!)
